# C Segmentation Fault when calling scanf()

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void createAndBootQcow2(char size) {
    char img[500];
    printf("Enter Image path: ");
    scanf("%s", img);
    
    char command_string_1[200];
    char command_string[200];
    
    strcpy(command_string_1, "qemu-img create -f ");
    strcpy(command_string, &size);
    
    strcat(command_string_1, command_string);
    
    //printf("%s", command_string);
    system(command_string);
};


void main() {
    char option;
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("-QEMU Manager-\n");
    printf("--------------\n");

    printf("Options\n");
    printf("1. Create qcow2 image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("2. Create raw image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("3. Create VMDK image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("4. Boot from selected image file\n");
    printf("5. Boot from configuration\n");

    scanf("%c", &option);

    char size[3];
    switch (option) {
        case '1':
            printf("Enter Virtual Hard Disk Size: ");
            scanf("%s", &size);
            createAndBootQcow2(&size);
            break;
        case  '2': 
            //createAndBootRaw();
            break;
        case  '3' :
            //createAndBootVmdk();
            break;
        case '4' : 
            //bootFromImage();
            break;
        case '5' :
            //loadLocalConfigAndBoot(); 
            break;
    };
}
```

Above is my code, it segfaults right where I define the disk size. Any ideas?
Note: I am relatively new to C, so there might be something obvious I'm missing.

I was expecting the program to take me to `createAndBootQcow2()` but instead it segfaults as mentioned above. What am I entering?
`Enter Virtual Hard Disk Size: 50G`

EDIT 1: Updated code to reflect changes, now getting `zsh trace trap` upon execution

EDIT 2: Updated code to show that `img` and `size` are strings not chars. Still getting `zsh: trace trap` but now somewhere in `createAndBootQcow2()`

EDIT 3: Updated code to show that ultimately I am calling `system(command_string)` to execute qemu-img. Still getting `zsh: trace trap` somewhere in `createAndBootQcow2()`

Comment: Remove all the irrelevant parts of the program.  And tell us what text you're entering at the prompt when you run it and it crashes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.  That would at least identify the `strcpy` being given a `char` argument.

Comment: I see no reason to think that the error occurs when you call `scanf`. The incorrect usage of `strcpy()`, on the other hand, is a prime candidate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How would I use strcpy() in my code? I'm a little confused.

Comment: `strcpy` is for copying *strings*.  A single `char` is not a string, unless it happens to contain the value `'\0'` (in which case it is an empty string).  And `strcpy` requires you to pass a *pointer to* the first characters of the destination and source strings.  Note well that switching to `&size` might change the program's behavior, but it's still not right, because `size` is not the first character of a string.  The revised program has a bounds overrun.

Comment: Instead of `strcpy` + `strcpy` + `strcat`, consider a single `sprintf`.

Comment: Your third edit shows `system()` called with the `command_string` buffer, but it appears you’re trying to build the command string in `command_string1`. Still, as others have pointed out `strcpy(command_string, &size)` doesn’t do what you want. Follow the advice and try `sprint()`.

Comment: @Connor-Tozer What text you're entering at the prompt when you run it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed up your code so that it runs:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void createAndBootQcow2(char size[]) {
    char img[500];
    printf("Enter Image path: ");
    scanf("%s", img);
    
    char base_command[20] = "qemu-img create -f ";

    char command_string_1[200];
    char command_string[200];
    
    strcpy(command_string_1, base_command);
    strcpy(command_string, size);
    
    strcat(command_string_1, command_string);
    
    printf("%s", command_string);
    system(command_string);
};


void main() {
    char option;
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("-QEMU Manager-\n");
    printf("--------------\n");

    printf("Options\n");
    printf("1. Create qcow2 image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("2. Create raw image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("3. Create VMDK image and boot from iso\n");
    printf("4. Boot from selected image file\n");
    printf("5. Boot from configuration\n");

    scanf("%c", &option);

    char size[5];
    switch (option) {
        case '1':
            printf("Enter Virtual Hard Disk Size: ");
            scanf("%s", &size);
            createAndBootQcow2(size);
            break;
        case  '2': 
            //createAndBootRaw();
            break;
        case  '3' :
            //createAndBootVmdk();
            break;
        case '4' : 
            //bootFromImage();
            break;
        case '5' :
            //loadLocalConfigAndBoot(); 
            break;
    };
}
```

There were some problems with the use of `&` and `*`, making you pass arguments of the wrong types into `strcpy` and `strcat`. Probably take a look at `strcpy` documentation with `man 3 strcpy`. Additionally, I made `char size` be of type `char size[]`.

Don't worry about the mistakes; I made the same mistakes when I started up with C (the evidence is somewhere on this site). I recommend you listen to the warnings GCC throws at you. The only real way to get used to pointers is to fix the warnings.

P.S. After I ran the fixed version of the code, I realized your `system` call doesn't do quite what I think you wanted it to do.

EDIT: @Eric Postpischil brought up an error I missed the first time around. `char size[3]` doesn't include a terminating null byte `\0` causing what I missed as another segfault. I made it five bytes for saftey.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: This does not fix the most critical error in the program, that `size` is defined as `char size[3];` but is used to read a string of three characters plus a terminating null byte, so it must hold at least four characters. Additionally, `scanf("%s", &size);` should be at least `scanf("%s", size);` and preferably `scanf("%3s", size);`. `main` should be declared to return `int`, not `void`.